# How to Access Data in Redux Store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building an application and am trying to show article content from mongoDB using axios, node.js, and express on a React frontend. I can pull the data to my redux store but when I try to display it I get a cannot read property 'author' (or whatever property in the state I'm going for) of undefined error.
Here are some screenshots of my react file, as well as the action and reducer. Let me know what other info you might need. Thanks a ton.[Here is my React file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IgfW.png). [Here is the action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHVJ3.png). [here is my reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC8m7.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A couple of tips to help you improve your chances of getting an answer: first, don't post images of your code - post the actual code as text so people can copy/paste it, run it, etc. Second, include as much information as you can about the error - do you know what line the error occurs on? which file?

Comment: @Kryten Thank you for the tips! I will make sure to post the actual code as text moving forward. I was able to figure it out on my own after being stuck for a good week this morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the initial of state is empty object `{}`. So while fetching API, `state.articles` is `undefined` and this issue occur.

You can fix by add condition before using with `optional chaining`

```
const articles = useSelector((state => state.articles);
const current = articles?.current ;
```

Comment: This helped solve my issue. I also set the content to conditionally render only if 'current' on the redux store was not empty. This seemed to fix any issue I might've been having with the page attempting to show data prior to the completion of fetching the data.